# TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Add which has no callable sin method

Tags: python, numpy

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import simpy as sp
init_printing()

var('x,y,z')

a = math.sqrt(10/7)    
c = (y-math.sqrt(18/7)-1)    
b = np.sin(math.pi/2*c)-z

f = lambda x,y,z: x**2+y**2+z**2-4
g = lambda x, y, z: (9/2)*(x**2+z**2)+y**2-9
h = lambda y, z: np.sqrt(10/7) * np.sin((np.pi/2) * y - np.sqrt(18/7)-1)- z
         
F = [[f(x, y, z)],
     [g(x, y, z)],
     [h(y, z)]]
```

As I try to define the fuction `h(x)` I get this:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AttributeError: 'Add' object has no attribute 'sin'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-da3a7e28861c> in <module>

         10 a = math.sqrt(10/7)
     11 c = (y-math.sqrt(18/7)-1)
---> 12 b = np.sin((math.pi/2*c))-z
     13 
     14 

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Add which has no callable sin method
```

I tried to separete the function in parts a, b and c so the error could be more easy to find. Now I know I have some problem with the `var('x, y, z')` and the `np.sin()/math.sin()`, but I can't find how to fix it.

Comment: First, your error is in one of the first lines. There is no need to post the rest of your code and pollute the question. Second, what is `var`? Where is it defined? (`init_printing()` is also undefined but I suppose it is irrelevant, anyway.) Overall, I believe you improperly mixed up NumPy and SimPy but there is not enough info in your question for a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

Pay close attention to the `type` of the variables.  When in doubt, check, don't just guess or assume

```
var('x,y,z')
```

these are `sympy` symbols (though here I'm guessing what `var` is doing)

```
a = math.sqrt(10/7)
```

this must be a python float, produced by the `math.sqrt` function.

```
c = (y-math.sqrt(18/7)-1)
```

Assuming `y` is sympy, then `c` itself is a `sympy` expression, probably an `Add`.

```
b = np.sin(math.pi/2*c)-z
```

`math.pi/2*c` is sympy expression.

`np.sin` is a numpy `ufunc`, and only works with numpy arrays.  That means it first does

```
np.array(math.pi/2*c)
```

making a single element object dtype array.

`np.sin` given an object dtype array, passes the task to the `sin` method of that object.  But noone defines a `sin` method.  It's always a function.

Using `np.sin`, or many other `numpy` functions on `sympy` expressions just does not work.  Don't mix `sympy` and `numpy` until you know what you are doing!

---

```
In [5]: sp.var('x,y,z')
Out[5]: (x, y, z)
In [6]: y
Out[6]: y
In [7]: a = math.sqrt(10/7)
   ...: c = (y-math.sqrt(18/7)-1)
In [8]: a
Out[8]: 1.1952286093343936
In [9]: c
Out[9]: y - 2.60356745147455
In [10]: type(c)
Out[10]: sympy.core.add.Add
In [11]: math.pi/2*c
Out[11]: 1.5707963267949*y - 4.08967418933897
In [12]: np.array(_)
Out[12]: array(1.5707963267949*y - 4.08967418933897, dtype=object)
In [13]: np.sin(_)
AttributeError: 'Add' object has no attribute 'sin'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-13-2b409a55b2a2>", line 1, in <module>
    np.sin(_)
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Add which has no callable sin method
```

### pure sympy

```
In [14]: a = sp.sqrt(10/7)
    ...: c = (y-sp.sqrt(18/7)-1)
In [15]: c
Out[15]: y - 2.60356745147455
In [16]: sp.pi/2*c
Out[16]: pi*(y - 2.60356745147455)/2
In [17]: sp.sin(sp.pi/2*c)
Out[17]: sin(pi*(y/2 - 1.30178372573727))
```